# Parametrized generic C macros

Tags: c, generics, c-preprocessor

I'm playing around with building a psuedo-generic type in C. Essentially, I'm trying to clone Rust's `Option<T>` with a predefined, constrained list of types allowable as `T`.

Obviously, C isn't really suited for this -- I'm doing this primarily to see how far I can go (as opposed to something I'd expect to use in real production code). To that end, any ugly hacks are fair game.

What I have so far builds out a separate set of inner-type-specific functions for all provided types. It looks something like this:

Header:

```
#pragma once

#define ALL_OPTIONS \
    OPTION_INSTANCE(option_bool, bool) \
    OPTION_INSTANCE(option_double, double) \
    OPTION_INSTANCE(option_int, int)

#define OPTION_INSTANCE(name, inner)                                          \
    typedef struct {                                                          \
        bool is_some;                                                         \
        inner val;                                                            \
    } name##_t;

ALL_OPTIONS

#undef OPTION_INSTANCE

#define OPTION_INSTANCE(name, inner)                                          \
    name##_t name##_some(inner val);                                          \
    name##_t name##_none(void);                                               \
    bool name##_is_some(name##_t self);                                       \
    bool name##_is_none(name##_t self);                                       \

ALL_OPTIONS

#undef OPTION_INSTANCE
```

Implementation:

```
#include "option.h"

#define OPTION_INSTANCE(name, inner) \
    name##_t name##_some(inner val) {                                         \
        return (name##_t) {                                                   \
            .is_some = true,                                                  \
            .val = val,                                                       \
        };                                                                    \
    }                                                                         \
                                                                              \
    name##_t name##_none(void) {                                              \
        return (name##_t) {                                                   \
            .is_some = false,                                                 \
        };                                                                    \
    }                                                                         \
                                                                              \
    bool name##_is_some(name##_t self) {                                      \
        return self.is_some;                                                  \
    }                                                                         \
                                                                              \
    bool name##_is_none(name##_t self) {                                      \
        return !self.is_some;                                                 \
    }

ALL_OPTIONS

#undef OPTION_INSTANCE
```

Note that in my actual code I have many more functions defined for the generated types.

This works well enough, though primarily all I've done is reduce implementation boilerplate. The next step would be to implement `option_is_some` (no type qualification) which can accept *any* `option_<inner>_t`

I can do that well enough with a manual macro, leveraging C11 generics:

```
#define option_is_some(self)                                                  \
    _Generic((self),                                                          \
        option_bool_t: option_bool_is_some,                                   \
        option_double_t: option_double_is_some,                               \
        option_int_t: option_int_is_some,                                     \
    )(self)
```

but this necessarily duplicates the list of types defined in `ALL_OPTIONS`. What I'd really like to do would be something like

```
#define OPTION_INSTANCE(name, inner) \
    name##_t: name##_is_some,

#define option_is_some(self)                                                  \
    _Generic((self),                                                          \
        ALL_OPTIONS                                                           \
        default: false                                                        \
    )(self)

#undef OPTION_INSTANCE
```

but that fails, since `ALL_OPTIONS` is expanded when `option_is_some` is used (where `OPTION_INSTANCE` will be undefined).

So, I'm looking for alternatives. I'd happily move to a radically different method of defining a generic list of types (instead of the `ALL_OPTIONS` hack) -- however, I do want to preserve the property that adding a new supported inner type only requires a change in a single location.

Answer (score 0):

Just access the member in the macro itself:

```
 #define option_is_some(self)  ((self).is_some)
```

---

Overall, your implementation is strange. Do not have a central `ALL_OPTIONS` place - do one option at a time, separately from each other. Files are split into headers and source files in C.

```
#define OPTION_HEADER(name, inner) \
    typedef struct {                                                          \
        bool is_some;                                                         \
        inner val;                                                            \
    } name##_t; \
\
    name##_t name##_some(inner val);                                          \
    name##_t name##_none(void);                                               \
    bool name##_is_some(name##_t self);                                       \
    bool name##_is_none(name##_t self);

#define OPTION_SOURCE(name, inner) \
    name##_t name##_some(inner val) {                                         \
        return (name##_t) {                                                   \
            .is_some = true,                                                  \
            .val = val,                                                       \
        };                                                                    \
    }     \
    etc...

#define OPTION_HEADER_AND_SOURCE(name, ...) \
       OPTION_HEADER(name, __VA_ARGS__)
       OPTION_SOURCE(name, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Then you would just do the options:

```
OPTION_HEADER_AND_SOURCE(option_bool, bool)
OPTION_HEADER_AND_SOURCE(option_double, double)
OPTION_HEADER_AND_SOURCE(option_int, int)
```

You can take a look at other projects that I've found: https://github.com/tylov/STC and https://github.com/glouw/ctl that use macro-ish templates to implement in C various container known from C++.